# How to fix layout(view location) from Android to an iOS and vice-versa?

Tags: android, ios, swift, android-studio

Currently, We are working on project and we are facing issue with story creation the issue is that if we create story post in android and add some tags and links and views it in iOS than it did not match to the android story post its huge layout issue and same happens in iOS if we create story in iOS than view it in android it is not matching with android story post.

**The major issue with x, y & width, height of components and the scaling, rotation of the components.**

[Reference post](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HUiP0.png)

First of all we create square post based on device width like 1080*1080, 720*720 etc in android and add one component and that post as you shown in image and post save on the server like background image and component details like x, y & width, height of components and the scaling, rotation and same post get in iOS device but it is not showing like android post currently we are use base width of post and resize all components like x,y and height, width based on it

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow. Could you provide a minimal example?